# Change an array with associative keys into an array with indexed keys

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I want to change the key of my array in php.

Here an exemple :

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'iden' => string '01' (length=8)
      'don' => string '17' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'iden' => string '02' (length=8)
      'don' => string '17' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'iden' => string '03' (length=8)
      'don' => string '17' (length=2)
```

And I want to change my array like this :

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '01' (length=8)
      1 => string '17' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '02' (length=8)
      1 => string '17' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '03' (length=8)
      1 => string '17' (length=2)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the array_values function to remove named keys:

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $item = array_values($item);
}
unset($item); // Remove reference
```

Note the & in the foreach. This creates a reference in the $item variable to the corresponding array element which means you can edit it in your loop.

If you want, you can also write this in a single line using array_map:

```
$array = array_map("array_values", $array);
```